# Nginx multi store as /pt

Tags: nginx, magento2, multistore

We have magento2 webstore with enable multi store.
Example:

- `/domain.com` - main store (Spanish)
- `domain.com/pt` - Portugal web store

We did nginx vhost with mapping:

```
map $request_uri $MAGE_RUN_CODE {
  domain.com website;
  /pt pt;
}
```

then we add the variables in magento2 nginx sample config:

```
....
fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE website;
fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE $MAGE_RUN_CODE;
....
```

Also we enabled in magento2 backend `GENERAL->WEB->Add` Store Code to `Urls=YES`

Everything starts working fine, but that option (Add Store Code to Urls) rewrite main store URLs with the language code (es).

For example the urls of main (Spanish) store are now like domain.com/es/product1.html.

We are looking for workaround to remove the `'es'` URI store code only from main website.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the pt sub directory and then do these  barring any nginx differences. It should be similar.

If this were apache you'd copy your index.php and .htaccess (or any nginx equivilent you need) into the sub folder. Then alter your index.php with a switch on $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] the case statement is on your domain. In that case statement set the run code and run type. Then when the $bootstrap is created in create() the paramaters are BP and your $params array with the run code and run type in them. Where you have your require statment in the same file add a .. to the beginning to go up a directory when it's looking for the file. Then change the base link url and secure base link url for that particular store to the link for your pt store, while keeping the base url etc the same your your main store. I hope that makes enough sense to you.  has the full php code. All you need to the switch, the alterations to $bootstrap and the require line.the base link url changes I mentioned get around the need for any messing around in pub.